# Given a corner, draw a square of known size minimizing vertex distance to a point

Tags: geometry, rotations

I've been going a little crazy trying to solve this what I think is a simple problem.

**Given:**

- A known corner ($\sim 90^\circ$) as defined by $\angle ABC$. Segment $AB$ is defined by two points on $AB$ with coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$. Segment $BC$ is defined by two points on $BC$ with coordinates $(x_3, y_3)$ and $(x_4, y_4)$.
- length of the green square is $S$
- An arbitrary point $P$ with coordinates $(x, y)$.
- Have access to matrix library if that significantly can simplify the problem.
- four corners of green square are called $A$, $D$, $E$, $F$.

**Want:**

- Calculate the coordinates of the four corners ($A$, $D$, $E$, $F$) of the square, minimizing the sum of distances of each vertex to point $(x, y)$. i.e., $\text{minimize} (PA+PD+PE+PF)$

[image: diagram]

Green square is what I want, red square would not be.

**What I've thought:**
To solve this, although this method seems horribly inefficient, I propose the following:

1. Take points AB and compute the angle formed.
2. Compute the point distance S away from point B along step 1 angle and along (step 1: $\text{angle} + 180^\circ$)
3. Select which point is closer to the arbitrary point.
4. Repeat the steps then for points BC, which after this step I should have 3 points of the square.

**What I'm wondering** is if there is some way instead to perhaps rotate the coordinate frame so that the angle is aligned to cartesian coordinates (and the arbitrary point $(X, Y)$, compute the square, rotate all coordinates then back? This is similar to what I found [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195141/rotating-2d-coordinates) I see they converted everything to polar coordinates, but not 100% sure.

Comment: can you add D, E, F to your green square in the figure?

Comment: I still cannot grasp what $B$ and $C$ have to do with the square you are looking for. Must $D$ lie on $BC$ and $F$ lie on $AB$? If so, please state it.

Comment: Moreover, the depicted green square seems to have a vertex in $B$, not in $A$.